# Unknown exception when saving big object

Tags: big-object

We are getting following error while inserting big object:

```
    [UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION] UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: java.lang.RuntimeException 
    java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: 
    com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.io.IOException: Could                         
    not set up IO Streams
```

Any suggestions, how we could handle it?

Below is the code that might throwing the exception:

```
    App_Log__b appLog = new App_Log__b();
    appLog.Tag__c = tag;
    appLog.Logging_Level__c = level.name();
    appLog.Created_DateTime__c = System.now();
    appLog.User__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
    appLog.IPfolio__Log__c = message;
    appLog.IPfolio__Log_Type__c = logType.name();
    Database.SaveResult sRes = Database.insertImmediate(appLog);
```

Thanks,

Kostas

Comment: Usually I'd say just "post your code so we can help" but it is pretty unusual to see a Java runtime exception while working with the platform. I'd advise to just open a case with Salesforce support instead.

Comment: It would definitely help if you share your code which results in the error above.

Comment: I updated initial post. Unfortunately, we were not able to find all logs. We spotted this error in Apex Jobs screen. @RenatoOliveira we opened a case in SF support but we were wondering if someone else encountered this and is so, how they dealt with it.

Comment: Well, I said that because of the error message. You can see that there's a "master not running" exception, and a "could not set up IO streams" exception. That's definitely an internal issue, not related to your code.